# How does heat transfer from a processor depend on fan speed in a computer (graph)?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I've tried web search, several variants of query, many links and lots of scientific data on heat transfer, including wiki pages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer), but I had not found an answer to that simple (IMO) particular question. I was thinking about asking it on physics SE, but still decided here is more relevant and of interest to others, please comment if you think otherwise.

What is the relationship of heat transfer from e.g. a processor and fan speed? Please provide a graph. Basically I want to know: increasing fan speed say two times would result in how much increase of heat transfer? Does it depend (if so than how) on ambient vs. current processor (or rather heat sink) temperature difference?

Comment: I don't think you can actually calculate it like this. I think it depends on a lot more factors like room temperature, air intake of the computer case, size of the fan, ...

Comment: I have a new desktop with a fan over the CPU and a molded cover directly to the outside of the case. All solid state, runs very cool and draws a total idle power of 15 watts including the monitor. So this kind of engineering overrides any kind of standard thermal average calculations.

Comment: @John, cover of the fan? If you want me to appreciate the design, please provide link where there is a picture ;-)

Comment: The moulding covers the whole fan and CPU. If you want a picture, I will have to provide an answer and when I do that I would be happy for acknowledgment. I will be back shortly with a picture.

Comment: “Please provide a graph.” - Impossible with the information you provided. What your asking for requires numerous inputs to calculate thermal transfer of a heatsink

Answer (score 1):

The reason for my comment (that modern computers run very cool - room temperature and the Fan runs at a modest and quiet speed - the computer cannot be heard in a quiet room).

So then making the Fan run faster would not help because you cannot (practically) cool a computer to lower than ambient room temperature.

The Fan has a housing the covers the CPU, the Fan and exhausts air to the outside of the case. To my hand, the temperature is not even warm.

Power draw of this computer at idle, normal browsing and simple spreadsheets including monitor is 15 to 20 watts.

This computer is a Lenovo M70s small form factor with a motherboard, a CPU, a Power Supply (with its own fan) and a drive bay with a CD. It has 16 GB of memory, a 1 TB NVMe SSD and a 2 TB Sata SSD (3 TB of space), and a high end i5 and runs Windows 11 Pro.

This is a very nice computer overall (and given the quality construction and the shortage of commercial stuff currently) it was not a doorbuster special.

The pictures are (a) the Fan housing and (b) the inside of the computer. Picture (b) is on the PC side and the Drive Bay on the right side is the front of the Computer. The Power Supply is on the left side looking down. The CPU is on the right side looking down.

The computer (covers on of course) is in an enclosed cupboard at the right side of the desk with vent holes in the back. Temperature inside the cupboard is 22 degrees thereabouts, room temperature is 20 degrees and the exhaust air at the back of the computer is cool to the hand (body temperature is 39 degrees)

.

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: Good for you. I too use Lenovo devices, but laptops, and their fans are much smaller and noisier ;-( Hence I wanted to find out what minimal speed would be significantly better than zero. Currently lowest ~ 1000 rpm and I thought maybe 100 is not significantly worse and wanted to find data.

Comment: btw is it really 'has 1GB of memory'? probably a misprint as Win 11 requirements state 4GB+

Comment: The machine has 16 GB of memory (typo on my part corrected - thanks).  My Laptop (X1 Carbon) also runs cool and the Fan normally is at low speed. There is a higher speed if I am installing a big app / update, but normally slow.  So that may be closer to what you want (older machine). But my newer Desktop seems to also run slow. The purpose of the main fan is to cool the CPU and prevent overheating, but newer designs and cooling methods seem to accomplish this without a high speed fan.

Comment: @maybe it depends on quality of the fan ... As I've mentioned by wanting 100 rpm on my laptops 1000 is too noisy for me (I want fan slower, not faster). But maybe I'm more intolerant to noise than you, w/out proper noise measuring device it would be hard to tell IMO. I've recently watched a video how to make a fan less noisy by putting in on a foam/glue instead of bolts, but I cannot imagine (at least yet) how to do that to a laptop...

Comment: Of course, quality of parts (including Fan) are very important. The combination of low speed and good parts makes for a quiet experience. I don't think I would mess with the mounting., however.